# Why does Vector2.one have to be normalized in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I found the following code in a [unity pong tutorial](http://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-pong-game):

```
// Give the ball some initial movement direction
rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.one.normalized * speed;
```

Does anyone know the point of normalizing Vector2.one? As far as I understand, the vector one is (1,1) and normalized already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of `(1, 1)` is `sqrt(2)`, not `1`.

The normalised version will be `(sqrt(0.5), sqrt(0.5))`.